# .NET property grid location issue

Tags: c#, localization

I have a piece of code to show which sections can be customized by users.

```
System.Attribute[] atts = new Attribute[] {
                new CategoryAttribute("Appearance"),
                new CategoryAttribute("Chart"),
                new CategoryAttribute("Image")
            };
uxPropertyGridChart.BrowsableAttributes = new AttributeCollection(atts);
```

It worked fine with CultureInfo("en-US"). But it throws exception with other locations (e.g. fr-FR). I'm curious to know why.

Any ideas?

Edit:
I posted the answer below in case anyone has the same problem.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Knowing the exception information is the first step to understanding your problem.

Comment: Yeye, I forgot to post the exception. You don't have to downvote my question. Anyway, I found the answer myself. See below if anyone has the same problem.

Comment: the point of down voting is to encourage posters to provide adequate information so there is a context to your question, it helps future searches for related problems and matches to the exception.  If you post the exception the down vote will go away.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute section has to be location specific. So in my case, the "Chart" should be changed to "Graphique" in French.